# Proper use of wp_get_attachment_image?

Tags: attachments, media-library

I have two images attached to a page. One is being used as the featured image, and I want the other to automatically be displayed at the designated spot in the template (within the loop)  at full size. The image I want is the first image attachment, so as I understand, I should be able to simply use:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(1, 'full'); ?>
```

But, this is returning nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the `1` an example ID, or are you trying to use `1` as the attachment ID(i very much doubt there's an attachment with that ID).

Answer (score 5):

Don't you need to use `get_posts( 'post_type=attachment' )` to return the attachment IDs? So, something like:

```
$args = array( 
     'post_type' => 'attachment', 
     'numberposts' => -1, 
     'post_status' => null, 
     'post_parent' => $post->ID 
);    
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
$myimageid = $attachments[0]->ID;

wp_get_attachment_image( $myimageid, 'full' );
```

Otherwise, you're using $post->ID of 1, which isn't likely to work.

Comment: ID of 1 is guaranteed to fail, since the default installation post has that ID number no matter what.